# How can I run a Mac OS Classic program on Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mac-os-classic

Is it possible to run a Mac OS Classic application on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You can try emulating classic using [SheepShaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/) (which may work or not) or something similar though.

What I would recommend is to try as hard as one can to find a replacement for the app; there's bound to be something newer that does the same (or similar) thing.